# IndexError: list index out of range in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5

I am learning Python 3. I have two lists:

```
A = [12, 28, 46, 32, 50]
B = [50, 12, 32, 46, 28]
```

If A and B have any items common, a third list should return them (with their index in B).

```
[1, 4, 3, 2, 0]
```

I am getting the below error,

```
Line 6: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
class Solution:
    def anagramMappings(self, A, B):
        result =[]
        for i in A:
            for j in B:
                if A[i]==B[i]:
                        result.append(j)
        return result
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers. I figured out the below solution. It works for most test cases except this,

```
Input:
[40,40]
[40,40]
Output:
[0,0,0,0]
Expected:
[1,1]
```

Code:

```
class Solution:
    def anagramMappings(self, A, B):
        result =[]
        for i in A:
            for j in B:
                if i==j:
                        result.append(B.index(j))
        return result
```

Comment: For starters: `if A[i]==B[i]:` should be `if A[i]==B[j]:`
`

Comment: `for i in A:` will have the value 12 for the 1st iteration, which is more than the length of list A. Hence, the error. You will need `if i == j` instead. Of course, this can be simplified by using python idioms.

Comment: See what python offers in terms of constructs especially when you are coming from other language. i.e. index based array iteration (`for var=i; i < len(list); i++`) compared to `for i in list` (enumeration where item is returned instead of index). See list iteration and list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python for loop iterates over the elements, not the indicies. So the if statement on first hit is evaluating to `A[12] == B[50]`, which I don't think you want here. Try `if i == j` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> *You are iterating over the elements and **not** the indices of A & B.*

The line:
`for i in A` will iterate over the list and return `12,28..` and similar output will be for the B list as well.

But you are supposed to iterate `i` and `j` over the indices, so you get their length by `len(A)` and `len(B)` and then convert it into an iterable by using python's [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function.
Your code should be like:

```
  class Solution:
        def anagramMappings(self, A, B):
            result =[]
            for i in range(len(A)):
                for j in range(len(B)):
                    if A[i]==B[j]:
                            result.append(j)
            return result
```